# Prove that $\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}} \geq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, contest-math, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> If $a,b,c$ are positive reals and $abc=1$, Prove that
> $$\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}} \geq \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$$

My try:
$$\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}}=\frac{b+c+a-a}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a+b-b}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b+c-c}{\sqrt{c}}$$
$\implies$
$$\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c}}=(a+b+c)(\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{b}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{c}})-(\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c})$$
Is there a way from here?

Comment: The inequality is very weak: stronger inequality proved here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3984909/find-the-value-of-k-in-fracbc-sqrta-fracca-sqrtb-fracab/3984926#3984926

Comment: As $$\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}+3> \sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{c}$$ the result follows

Comment: For your inequality, you don’t even need $abc=1.$ Also, Titus Lemma yields $LHS\geqslant 2\cdot(\sqrt a+\sqrt b+\sqrt c)$